# Can I specify a URL as the filepath for cron?

Tags: cron

I want to have cron execute a script every minute. The script will send an email to different people, as determined by the script (I don't want cron to email anything). Will the code below work, or does the filepath need to be structured differently?

```
MAILTO=""
* * * * * http://www.mydomain.com/myfile.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not work. To have cron execute your php script you have two choices.

```
MAILTO=""
* * * * * lynx -dump http://www.mydomain.com/myfile.php
```

or

```
MAILTO=""
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /local/path/to/myfile.php
```

Instead of lynx you can of course use curl or other web clients. The latter will of course require the php script to be local.